# after coming back from one screen to other screen using stack navigator,life cycle not getting called,but showing ui

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 3 screens which are  created using stackNavigator.When I navigate to screen 2 from screen 1 I am using this.props.navigation.push("screen 2") ,same way I  did for screen 2 to screen 3.

Now I am at screen 3 and I should navigate in the same order to screen 1,so I used this.props.navigation.goBack().

I am able to navigate to screen1 from screen 3 as I expected, but Ui is showing without calling life cycle.But I want to change the ui when I come back from screen 3 to screen 1,

```
 class screen1 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View>

                <Button onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.push('screen2')
                }}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.goBack()
                }}>
                    <Text>go back to previous screens</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
}


class screen2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View>

                <Button onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.push('screen3')
                }}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => .
                {this.props.navigation.goBack()}}>
                    <Text>go back to previous screens</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
}


class screen3 extends Component{

    render() {
        return (

            <View>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.goBack()
                }}>
                    <Text>go back to previous screens</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your constructor.I hope it will helps you.

```
    this.props.navigation.addListener(
                 'didFocus',
                 payload => {
                    // this.componentDidMount();
                      call function which you want to call
                 });
```

Comment: I added it in constructor of  screen 1,but it is giving the error "Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined" . @Komal Sakhiya

Comment: It worked after removing this keyword before props but only render function is called.Inside a method I am calling componentWillMount and componentDidMount, but not getting called  @Komal Sakhiya

Comment: We can call any function in payload

Answer (score 0):

React prevents unnecessary rendering of the elements. If a screen is already present on a stack lets say as a parent screen and if you go to some another screen from that stack and then come back again to the parent screen then the parent screen's life cycle will not be called because that screen is already mounted on the stack.

You can solve this issue by three major methods :

1. Using Redux, update the store and then release or fire some reducers which will cause an update to the screen and the screen will be refreshed.
2. [Using componentDidUpdate, componentShouldUpdate, componentDidReceiveProps, you can re trigger the state and cause an refresh.](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html)

example :

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ refresh: nextProps.refresh });
  }
```

3. Using navigation action by using did focus, will focus, will blur, did blur etc to call an function whenever the screen comes on focus.

example :

```
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
 componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

export default withNavigation(Your Class Name);
```